# HTTP multipart classes in java

Tags: java, http

I'm trying to follow the answer to [THAT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943246/android-post-file-and-text) question

But it seems that classes are not included with the default Android package since for that code:

```
File file = new File("FileToSend.txt");
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

String url = "http://www.yourdomain.com/destination.php";
PostMethod postMethod = new PostMethod(url);

Part[] parts = {new FilePart(file.getName(), file)};
postMethod.setParameter("name", "value"); // set parameters like this instead in separate call

postMethod.setRequestEntity( new MultipartRequestEntity(parts, postMethod.getParams()));

int status = client.executeMethod(postMethod);
```

I have the following errors:

```
Cannot instantiate the type HttpClient
FilePart cannot be resolved to a type XXXXX.java
MultipartRequestEntity cannot be resolved to a type XXXXX.java
Part cannot be resolved to a type XXXXX.java
PostMethod cannot be resolved to a type XXXXX.java
```

How can I solve those errors, is there some library I must add? if yes please let me know how can I download it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`HttpClient` is (now) an interface. Use `DefaultHttpClient` instead. Here's replacement classes for some of the others you listed:

```
FilePart - FileBody
MultipartRequestEntity - MultipartEntity
Part - ContentBody
PostMethod - HttpPost
```