# Attach files from file system to the application

Tags: android, file-management

How can I implement ability to attach files from file system to my application. Can I use some libraries, or I should do it myself programmatically? Or I can implement code of other similar application and use them?

Comment: have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733195/android-intent-filter-for-a-particular-file-extension)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**File browser:**

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4895104/file-browser-in-android)

A sample code for file browser. Or you can just let user input the location into an `EditText` and let app remember it.

To use external storage(like SD card), please see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal)

**Remember the file location:**

[Using Shared Preferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref)

It is a simpler way to save persistent data than SQLite database

**Send it to server:**

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4943246/android-post-file-and-text)

Here is an example of how to use HTTP POST to send to server

Comment: ok, thank you. But should I put it with some other file manager or write my own one?

Comment: @user1512250 Do you mean you need to add files from android external storage to your own application?

Comment: I mean to add files from my file system

Comment: so you are concerned about write files to an external storage?

Comment: I want to implement ability to attach files from my file system to the application, like you attach files to your letter in the email client. And also provide an ability to send these files to the server...

Comment: Hmm, first you need to know the location of your files. Then just let the application remember it and send it to the server. Is my understanding right?

Comment: yes...user should choose files from his file system, we should to remember paths of them in the file system and send them to the server after that...

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/15726/discussion-between-combozhc-and-user1512250)